# How to print large invoice pdf from html template with automatic page breaks?

Tags: python, django, reportlab, xhtml2pdf

**With less products** [image: If items are less - works fine with a5 paper size]
 **With more products** [image: When items are more - white space on right side adds up]
 **Keeps getting worse** [image: When list of products is large]
**With** `table {-pdf-keep-in-frame-mode: overflow;}` **data truncates**
[image: data truncates with overflow]

Am using **XHTML2PDF** library in django python, i have tried out:

- `@frame`, it works but truncates content even with `{-pdf-keep-in-frame-mode: shrink;}`
- cant use: `pdf:nextpage` tag
- `p { margin: 0; -pdf-keep-with-next: true; }` and putting table data in paragraph

  What i want is:
  When the products size grows, if they fall off page, the page shall break automatically, and rest of products shall be printed to next page.
  Note: Am using single html template

  I can't use `pdf:nextpage` as:
- The product name (size) varies highly, so can't break page after 5 items or 10, and I have to use html template only, cant use **reportlab** tags.
   

  HTML:

```html
<html>
Not actual HTML code, but looks like
<style>
@page {
            size: a5 portrait;
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
table {    -pdf-keep-in-frame-mode: shrink;}
<style>
<body>
<table><tbody><tr><th> ---------- Removing this line, everything works fine!

{% for data in products %}
<table><tr><td>{{data.product_name}}<table><tr><td>
    <tr><td>{{data.mrp}}<table><tr><td>
    <tr><td>{{data.selling_price}}<table><tr><td></table>
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>

</th></tr></tbody></table> ----------- and corresponding closing tags
```

Some Dummy Data:

```
products_list = [
            {'product_name': 'Amul Cow Milk , 500ml', 'mrp': 20.0, 'selling_price': 20.0},
            {'product_name': 'Amul Cow Milk , 500ml', 'mrp': 20.0, 'selling_price': 20.0},
            {'product_name': 'Amul Cow Milk , 500ml', 'mrp': 20.0, 'selling_price': 20.0},]
```

Python Django API looks like:

```
    # Render HTML to PDF
    context_dic = {"products": products_list}
    template = get_template("invoice.html")
    html = template.render(context_dic)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF(html, dest=response)
    if pisa_status.err:
        return "render-error"
    return response
```

Comment: what happens when the content is too large for a single page?

Comment: i have an image attached for that at top, it shrinks and white space on right side is added, i don't have much on html except the products list in invoice increases the page size. that is what i want help with

Comment: though i found error somehow ( that i have defined in html code snippet), but i don't want to remove inner table, so now my question is how do i do that?  Why does this happen? and also height=100% doesn't work in body style, while width=100% works fine, why?

Comment: obviously it makes outer table cell either collapse or shrink to the page itself, is there a better way to handle inner table? and sorry i didn't mention outer table in previous code!

Comment: You might consider using a commercial HTML-to-PDF tool, like [DocRaptor](https://docraptor.com) or [PrinceXML](https://www.princexml.com/). Weasyprint (an open-source project) also has some support. The browser-based engines do not support CSS paged media and have significantly less page break control. More details here: https://print-css.rocks/

Comment: Did you get any luck for black dot instead of rupee?

Comment: for page break you can use css  page-break-after:always; give this to one dive which has  all content end it when you want new page